# Improving the quality of badly recorded sound files

Tags: editing, processing, audio-recording

I have an audio file with a very bad recording (recording was made in very noisy conditions, at a conference). My recorder was too far from the speakers.

Do you have any idea about how to improve the sound quality? Do you know any good resource for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). [Here](http://www.podtopia.net/gettingstarted/removenoise_video.shtml) is a video tutorial on how to remove noise.

Answer (score 2):

I love Audacity, and I highly recommend it (but can only upvote sYinfo once...). For the sake of completeness, I'll also mention [Wavosaur](http://www.wavosaur.com/) - another free audio editor. I keep it handy with Audacity as it has better support for VST plugins and ASIO drivers.